# How to change display's position from command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts, multiple-monitors, xrandr, display-manager

How can I use the command prompt to do get the setup shown below?

[image]

Edit: I need the secondary display to be located to the left and half-way to the top of the primary display, as shown above.

The output of xrandr is:

> ```
>         Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1567, maximum 32767 x 32767
>     eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1280+487 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
>        1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9  
>        1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
>        1600x1024      60.2  
>        1400x1050      60.0  
>        1280x1024      60.0  
>        1440x900       59.9  
>        1280x960       60.0  
>        1360x768       59.8     60.0  
>        1152x864       60.0  
>        1024x768       60.0  
>        800x600        60.3     56.2  
>        640x480        59.9  
>     VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>     DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>     HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>     HDMI2 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
>        1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
>        1920x1080      60.0     59.9  
>        1152x864       75.0  
>        1280x720       60.0     59.9  
>        1024x768       75.1     60.0  
>        800x600        75.0     60.3  
>        640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
>        720x400        70.1  
>     VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> ```

Comment: You can do it by "xrandr" command. "man xrandr" has help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `xrandr`. Also, please explain what you need. Are you expecting one screen to be above the other? By how much? Do you just need one screen to be on the right of the other one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output of xrandr shows 1024x768+1366+0; what does it mean and can I change it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614145/output-of-xrandr-shows-1024x76813660-what-does-it-mean-and-can-i-change-it)

Comment: Please take a look at the dupe I marked your question as. Strictly taken I am doubting if it is a *literal* dupe, however, the answer I would post would be a 100% copy. If you don't agree, please leave a comment and I'll remove the dupe mark.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

`xrandr --output eDPI1 --mode 1024x768 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI2 --mode 1366x768 --pos 1024x384 --rotate normal`

Comment: That's a lot more than strictly needed. Simply `xrandr --output eDPI1 --pos <x>x<y>` would do :)

Comment: <.< shhh, I copied settings from lxrandr, I've no idea what I am doing

Comment: haha, You are the best :)

Comment: On my turn, I simply copied `eDPI1` from your answer, while op does not have a screen like  that :)

Comment: wait what ? OP posted output of xrandr which reports eDPI1 there. Did I miss something ?

Comment: Oh dear, I should learn to read some day.

Comment: @JacobVlijm we need more coffee XD

Comment: I actually modified your script into `xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1280x512 --rotate normal`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Eduardo, that works  :) youre very welcome

Comment: I used `--size` instead of `--mode`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Yep, that's a good one too. Just keep in mind, `--size` is actually something different than `--mode`.  The `--size` option sets the size of the "virtual" or "software" screen. For single monitor setup ( like a laptop for example ) that's going to behave the same, but on dual monitor setups that it's obviously different.

Comment: I needed it to solve [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532727/dual-monitor-setup-one-monitor-has-double-width-and-scrolls-into-other-monitor), but then the displays were not relatively aligned anymore